# Is facebook connect supposed to replace traditional user account creation?

Tags: facebook

I have a game application for mobile. When signing new users up, I put them in a database table like:

```
id | email | username | password_hashed | etc
```

I'm not understanding what we do if we use facebook connect to let them "sign up" to the app. Is the idea to allow them to skip filling out a signup form altogether? Would I modify the user table to look like:

```
id | email       | username | password_hashed | optional_fb_id
---------------------------------------------------------------    
 1   foo@foo.com    foo          xyz              null
 2   null           grok         null             789
```

The idea being that if they sign up the "normal" way, they'd have to give me their email address, and a password for their account (row 1). If they signup using facebook connect, I don't need their email or a password, I just store their facebook id instead? (row 2).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely store the Facebook user ID to associate the user with their Facebook account. I would suggest checking out the [documentation that Facebook provides regarding the Registration plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/).

Comment: That makes sense, but is it as secure as having a password? That is, could someone sneak into there and impersonate a user by supplying an ID in between the login process somehow?

Comment: The documentation states "The data is passed to your application as a signed request. The `signed_request` parameter is a simple way to make sure that the data you're receiving is the actual data sent by Facebook. It is signed using your application secret which is only known by you and Facebook. If someone were to make a change to the data, the signature would no longer validate as they wouldn't know your application secret to also update the signature." Therefore, I would say it as secure as one's Facebook session (i.e. an attacker would need to be logged in or hijack the session somehow).